# Query to find the unique code in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

can some one suggest a query to send the unique errorcode count.

Example  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDb34.png)  2006

in between the tags(in place of 2006) different codes are printed
i need to query to pull all the unique error codes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rex` command to extract the desired values. It will look something like this:

```
your_initial_query
| rex field=_raw "<com:errorCode>(?<code>.*)<\/com:errorCode>"
| stats count by code
```

The second line tells `rex` to extract everything between the errorCode tags and save that to a field called `code`. You can then use the `stats` command to count the number of times a code is seen.